# URL that targets div with ID and has form values in it

Tags: html

I have some buttons (links) on my webpage which has a link with values in it so it filters the content on the page. The filter part is working fine but I can't get it to focus on the ID.

The current href value is:

> website/?type=Appartment&submit2=#

What I want is that it goes directly to the div named houses so it does not keep going to the top.

I tried making the URL like this:

> website/#houses?type=Appartment&submit2=#

But the above does not do anything at all.

**Summary:**
How do I target a div and have the form values in the URL at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `website/?type=Appartment&submit2=#houses`?

Comment: Yea that worked. I thought it had to be infront of the form values. Thanks!

Comment: "#" has an utility in url so i can only have one, try to uri encode it before !